# Filling in NaN values on monthly data using formula not working

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import rec,nan

df=pd.DataFrame.from_records(rec.array([
           ('Jan-22', 200., 100., 325.,  nan,  nan,  nan),
           ('Feb-22', 210., 101., 328.,  nan,  nan,  nan),
           ('Mar-22', 212., 102., 329.,  nan,  nan,  nan),
           ('Apr-22', 211., 104., 330.,  nan,  nan,  nan),
           ('May-22', 208., 105., 329.,  nan,  nan,  nan),
           ('Jun-22', 215., 107., 330.,  nan,  nan,  nan),
           ('Jul-22', 219., 108., 321.,  nan,  nan,  nan),
           ('Aug-22', 220., 105., 332.,  nan,  nan,  nan),
           ('Sep-22', 222., 111., 335.,  nan,  nan,  nan),
           ('Oct-22', 223., 115., 338.,  nan,  nan,  nan),
           ('Nov-22', 225., 118., 339.,  nan,  nan,  nan),
           ('Dec-22', 230., 122., 341.,  nan,  nan,  nan),
           ('Jan-23', 235., 124., 342., 17.5, 24. ,  5.2),
           ('Feb-23', 236., 126., 348., 12.4, 24.8,  6.1),
           ('Mar-23', 267., 128., 351., 25.9, 25.5,  6.7),
           ('Apr-23', 288., 130., 326., 36.5, 25. , -1.2),
           ('May-23', 299., 132., 359., 43.8, 25.7,  9.1),
           ('Jun-23', 300., 133., 363., 39.5, 24.3, 10. ),
           ('Jul-23',  nan,  nan,  nan, 12. , 11. ,  5. ),
           ('Aug-23',  nan,  nan,  nan, 11. , 12. ,  4. ),
           ('Sep-23',  nan,  nan,  nan, 10. , 11. ,  3. ),
           ('Oct-23',  nan,  nan,  nan,  9. , 13. ,  2. ),
           ('Nov-23',  nan,  nan,  nan,  8. , 14. ,  1. ),
           ('Dec-23',  nan,  nan,  nan,  7. ,  7. ,  4. ),
           ('Jan-24',  nan,  nan,  nan,  6. ,  8. ,  3. ),
           ('Feb-24',  nan,  nan,  nan,  6. ,  7. ,  1. ),
           ('Mar-24',  nan,  nan,  nan,  5. ,  8. ,  0. ),
           ('Apr-24',  nan,  nan,  nan,  4. ,  9. , -5. ),
           ('May-24',  nan,  nan,  nan,  3. , 10. , -5. ),
           ('Jun-24',  nan,  nan,  nan,  4. ,  5. , -4. ),
           ('Jul-24',  nan,  nan,  nan,  5. ,  4. , -2. ),
           ('Aug-24',  nan,  nan,  nan,  6. ,  2. , -1. ),
           ('Sep-24',  nan,  nan,  nan,  7. ,  2. , -4. ),
           ('Oct-24',  nan,  nan,  nan,  7. ,  2. , -4. ),
           ('Nov-24',  nan,  nan,  nan,  7. ,  2. , -4. ),
           ('Dec-24',  nan,  nan,  nan,  7. ,  2. , -4. )],
          dtype=[('date', 'O'), ('series1', '<f8'), ('series2', '<f8'), ('series3', '<f8'), ('series1_yoy', '<f8'), ('series2_yoy', '<f8'), ('series3_yoy', '<f8')]))

df = df.set_index('date')
```

Columns series1, series2 and series3 are level values while the corresponding columns with the same name and ending in yoy are the 12-month year over year percent change.

Starting in July 2023 I want to calculate series1, series2 & series3 by taking their values from 12 months ago and applying the provided growth rates with this code:

```
level_cols = ['series1','series2','series3']
yoy_cols = ['series1_yoy', 'series2_yoy', 'series3_yoy']

for i, x in enumerate(level_cols):
      df[x].fillna(df[x].shift(12) * (1 + df[yoy_cols[i]]/100), inplace=True)

df
```

However the code is only filling in series1, to series3 to June 2024, leaving out Jul 2024 to Dec 2024:

[image]

How do I modify the code so it fills in the calculated values through the entire range?  Can a counter variable be used here?

Comment: Just to confirm.  You want to compute compounded growth for months more than one year ahead of the data?  I.e. `df.loc['Dec-24', 'series1'] = df.loc['Dec-23', 'series1'] * (1 + df.loc['Dec-23', 'series1_yoy']/100)`. (=263.327)

Comment: Yes.  I have the growth rates I want to apply to the values 12 months prior which stops at June 2024.  I want the code to fully update the levels from Jul to Dec 2024.

Comment: Actually, my comment above is incorrect.  It should be `df.loc['Dec-24', 'series1'] = df.loc['Dec-23', 'series1'] * (1 + df.loc['Dec-24', 'series1_yoy']/100)`.

Answer (score 0):

Often, it's a case of reorganizing the data so that the task is easier.

```
# If it isn't already, convert index from strings to date times
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%b-%y')

# Create a Multi-index with year and month
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
    [df.index.year, df.index.month], 
    names=['Year', 'Month']
)

# Now re-organize it so that the months are in the column index
df = df.unstack('Month')

# Invert the column index so the months are in the top level
df.columns = df.columns.swaplevel(0, 1)
```

So now, for month 1 (Jan) we have:

```
print(df[1].head())
```

```
      series1  series2  series3  series1_yoy  series2_yoy  series3_yoy
Year                                                                  
2022    200.0    100.0    325.0          NaN          NaN          NaN
2023    235.0    124.0    342.0         17.5         24.0          5.2
2024      NaN      NaN      NaN          6.0          8.0          3.0
```

Now you can easily do compounded growth calculations for all the months

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
for month in range(1, 13):
    # Find last year of values
    last_year = df.loc[:, idx[month, level_cols]].last_valid_index()
    last_values = df.loc[last_year, idx[month, level_cols]].values.reshape(1, -1)
    yoy_growth = df.loc[last_year+1:, idx[month, yoy_cols]]
    compound_growth = (1 + yoy_growth / 100).cumprod().values
    df.loc[last_year+1:, idx[month, level_cols]] = last_values * compound_growth

# Restack it (for comparison)
df = df.stack('Month')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
             series1   series2   series3  series1_yoy  series2_yoy  series3_yoy
Year Month                                                                     
2022 1      200.0000  100.0000  325.0000          NaN          NaN          NaN
     2      210.0000  101.0000  328.0000          NaN          NaN          NaN
     3      212.0000  102.0000  329.0000          NaN          NaN          NaN
     4      211.0000  104.0000  330.0000          NaN          NaN          NaN
     5      208.0000  105.0000  329.0000          NaN          NaN          NaN
     6      215.0000  107.0000  330.0000          NaN          NaN          NaN
     7      219.0000  108.0000  321.0000          NaN          NaN          NaN
     8      220.0000  105.0000  332.0000          NaN          NaN          NaN
     9      222.0000  111.0000  335.0000          NaN          NaN          NaN
     10     223.0000  115.0000  338.0000          NaN          NaN          NaN
     11     225.0000  118.0000  339.0000          NaN          NaN          NaN
     12     230.0000  122.0000  341.0000          NaN          NaN          NaN
2023 1      235.0000  124.0000  342.0000         17.5         24.0          5.2
     2      236.0000  126.0000  348.0000         12.4         24.8          6.1
     3      267.0000  128.0000  351.0000         25.9         25.5          6.7
     4      288.0000  130.0000  326.0000         36.5         25.0         -1.2
     5      299.0000  132.0000  359.0000         43.8         25.7          9.1
     6      300.0000  133.0000  363.0000         39.5         24.3         10.0
     7      245.2800  119.8800  337.0500         12.0         11.0          5.0
     8      244.2000  117.6000  345.2800         11.0         12.0          4.0
     9      244.2000  123.2100  345.0500         10.0         11.0          3.0
     10     243.0700  129.9500  344.7600          9.0         13.0          2.0
     11     243.0000  134.5200  342.3900          8.0         14.0          1.0
     12     246.1000  130.5400  354.6400          7.0          7.0          4.0
2024 1      249.1000  133.9200  352.2600          6.0          8.0          3.0
     2      250.1600  134.8200  351.4800          6.0          7.0          1.0
     3      280.3500  138.2400  351.0000          5.0          8.0          0.0
     4      299.5200  141.7000  309.7000          4.0          9.0         -5.0
     5      307.9700  145.2000  341.0500          3.0         10.0         -5.0
     6      312.0000  139.6500  348.4800          4.0          5.0         -4.0
     7      257.5440  124.6752  330.3090          5.0          4.0         -2.0
     8      258.8520  119.9520  341.8272          6.0          2.0         -1.0
     9      261.2940  125.6742  331.2480          7.0          2.0         -4.0
     10     260.0849  132.5490  330.9696          7.0          2.0         -4.0
     11     260.0100  137.2104  328.6944          7.0          2.0         -4.0
     12     263.3270  133.1508  340.4544          7.0          2.0         -4.0
```

Please confirm if this is the desired result.

Comment: Actually, the unstacking and stacking is not essential.  You could do the calculations for each month using the MultiIndex, e.g. `df.loc[idx[:, month], :]`.

Comment: Actually, I think it's not correct.  Calculating the compound growth rates before is incorrect because old YoY growth rates should be ignored.  I will update the code now.

Comment: Thanks for replying....I repeated the loop, not sure its the best though:  for i, x in enumerate(level_cols):
      df_est[x].fillna(df_est[x].shift(12) * (1 + df_est[yoy_cols[i]]/100), inplace=True)
      for i, x in enumerate(level_cols):
         df_est[x].fillna(df_est[x].shift(12) * (1 + df_est[yoy_cols[i]]/100), inplace=True)

Comment: If that's your solution then it would be best to add it as an answer rather than a comment on my answer.